# SQL Query Comparison Processing Efficiency, Any Better Solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, processing-efficiency

I'm working in large set of data about 134 million line i would like to make a select query with a insert in a table.
This is my table [SQL script (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09951/2/0).

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id | Emitter    |   EmitterIBAN                         |  Receiver    |   ReceiverIBAN                           |         Adresss                          |     Value 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,   Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0002,        121.72
2,   Keene,         SK81 1004 7484 7505 6308 9259,        Torrance,       RO23 ZWTR OJKK VAU9 T5P4 2GDY,                  35197 Green Ridge Way,                   82.52
3,   Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0048,        51.81
4,   Korie,         ME43 9833 9830 7367 4239 60,Roy,      IL69            9686 1536 8102 2219 165,                        5 Swallow Alley,                         88.01
5,   Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0001,        133.99
6,   Charmine,      BG92 TOXX 8380 785I JKRQ JS,          Sarette,        MU67 RYRU 9293 5875 6859 7111 075X HR,          8 Sage Place,                            36.30
7,   Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0004,        186.99
```

And i select my data with this query

```
Select  count(1) as NumberOperation, 
        MAX(Emitter) as EmitterName, 
        EmitterIban, 
        MAX(Receiver) as ReceiverName, 
        ReceiverIban,
        MAX(ReceiverAddress) as ReceiverAddress,
        SUM([Value]) as SumValues
FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction
Group By EmitterIban,
         ReceiverIban
```

And i get the following result

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NumberOperation | Emitter    |   EmitterIBAN                         |  Receiver    |   ReceiverIBAN                           |         Adresss                          |     SumValue 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4,                Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point           0002,      494,51
1,                Keene,         SK81 1004 7484 7505 6308 9259,        Torrance,       RO23 ZWTR OJKK VAU9 T5P4 2GDY,                  35197 Green Ridge Way,                   82.52
1,                Korie,         ME43 9833 9830 7367 4239 60,Roy,      IL69            9686 1536 8102 2219 165,                        5 Swallow Alley,                         88.01
1,                Charmine,      BG92 TOXX 8380 785I JKRQ JS,          Sarette,        MU67 RYRU 9293 5875 6859 7111 075X HR,          8 Sage Place,                            36.30
```

I also have this solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   (SELECT Count(1)     AS NumberOperation, 
               emitteriban  AS _EmitterIban, 
               receiveriban AS _ReceiverIban, 
               Sum([value]) AS SumValues 
        FROM   tableesperadocetransaction 
        GROUP  BY emitteriban, 
                  receiveriban) tmp_T 
       LEFT JOIN tableesperadocetransaction 
              ON tableesperadocetransaction.emitteriban = tmp_T._emitteriban 
                 AND tableesperadocetransaction.receiveriban = 
                     tmp_T._receiveriban
```

And i would like to know what's the best solution between this two and if there's query more efficient than that?

Thanks

Comment: the first one should more efficent  .. you have not join and temporary table  .. so should work more fast ..

Comment: Try using SET STATISTICS IO ON; before running both and compare the number of Logical reads also see which runs faster!  Ultimately it depends on how your database is structured, especially regarding indexing

Comment: Well-written question, but I'm not sure it needed to be asked... surely it would be easier to just measure the real performance on your own server, rather than asking us which one will _probably_ be faster.

Comment: thanks @scaisEdge for your response; do you think there's a better solution that are better ?

Comment: @JeffUK didn't know that was possible thanks for the information but the problem is because i have a lot of data it's took me to much time to execute the queries and test them

Comment: @underscore_d yes for sure you're right but i don't now maybe i m doing something wrong but it's took more than 30 min i don't know if i have a network problem or else and that why i m asking here

Comment: @Esperadoce OK, so you should include in your question the results (or lack thereof) that you have already observed for both options. So then people won't just ask 'What have you tried?' They will know that you have tried something, and what it is, so they can proceed from the right point in helping.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the observation

Comment: Looking to your code .. is compact  .. and with only the essential ,, i don't think you could find a better solution (obviously firts query)

Comment: @scaisEdge okey thanks for for response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query is slower because:

1. It has a `LEFT JOIN`
2. It has a sub-query
3. It has a `SELECT DISTINCT`
4. Has a `*` instead of column names

The first one is the most natural way of doing this.

There is a lot about how to improve performance of queries and what to avoid. See for example: [MSDN on improving queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx#scalenetchapt14%20_topic7)

Comment: Hi @TheEsisia thanks for response and the link i think it's really important i should read it for future queries 
do you think there's a better solution for my case or the first one is enough

Comment: @Esperadoce Like I said, your first solution is very natural. Unless it causes issues, you don't need to change anything. But if it is very slow, you can consider adding indexes to your table as is explained in the link. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The 1st query should be far more efficient.

If you really want to speed things up, you'll want to make sure you have a covering index with EmitterIban, ReceiverIban as the key.

Comment: you mean create an index with EmitterIabn and ReceiverIban in one index excuse i m not good in sql and i would like to know why is this better than using one index  for  EmitterIban and one for ReceiverIban?

Comment: Yes... Based on your query, something along these lines...

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TableEsperadoceTransaction_EmitterIban_ReceiverIban ON dbo.TableEsperadoceTransaction (
 EmitterIban ASC,
    ReceiverIban ASC
 )
INCLUDE (
 Emitter,
 Receiver,
 ReceiverAddress,
 Value
 )
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY];

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

You get MIN(id), after use it for INNER JOIN. That is also a way.

```
SELECT
tmp.NumberOperation
,tb.Emitter
,tmp.EmitterIban
,tb.Receiver
,tmp.ReceiverIban
,tb.Adresss
,tmp.SumValues
FROM   (SELECT Count(1)     AS NumberOperation, 
               emitteriban  AS EmitterIban, 
               receiveriban AS ReceiverIban, 
               Sum([value]) AS SumValues,
               MIN(Id)      AS Id
        FROM   tableesperadocetransaction 
        GROUP  BY emitteriban, 
                  receiveriban) tmp
       INNER JOIN tableesperadocetransaction tb
              ON tableesperadocetransaction.id = tmp.Id
```